# Activity closes on button press

Tags: android

I'm having a bit of trouble with a simple app I'm making.

I'll include the code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import java.net.URL;


public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText user;
    EditText pass;
    boolean result_back;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogIn2);
        log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                login(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void login(View v)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTUser);
        String usuario = user.toString();
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTPass);
        String passw = pass.toString();
        String parametros = "?usuario=" + usuario + "&password=" + passw;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://gie.byethost.com/acces.php" + parametros);
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enviando datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast2.show();
        try
        {
            response = client.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        // response.toString();
        if (response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
        {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        } else
        if (response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }

    }
}
```

There's only one button here and neither toast is showing, so I don't see where the app is crashing. Also, I'm a bit new in Android programming, so this may have an obvious solution.

Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: oh the error is because you are using Network on main thread

Comment: you can use Break points to debug

Comment: I made a thread so that the transaction was made outside the main thread.
Now, when I press the button, it still crashes.

Do these logcat messages say something about it?

/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a network transaction on the main thread.  Never do that (or any blocking behavior) on the main thread.  Your app might be crashing with an error in logcat related to "StrictMode".

Instead, you need to put all your blocking work on another thread.  Android has very specific patterns about how to do that.  It's not like you would expect in a normal java app.

You might want to consider doing a search for "android asynchronous programming" and learn about things like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Loader](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Loader.html), and [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html).  There are a lot of great tutorials out there on how to use them.  Please don't use Thread directly, as that will only cause you pain.

Comment: Thank you very much, Doug

I tried changing my code to use AsyncTask and now it crashes as soon as I open the activity in question.

I changed the following:

        Button log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogIn2);
        log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
         new LongOperation().execute("");
        }
    });
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { login method contents here and a return   }